# How to add docker container hostname and network in Kubernetes Deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-network

I have docker images of different elk stacks, and I want to communicate between them. I have achieved it by creating a docker network and accessing them via hostname. I want to know if we can pass this properties in the kubernetes or not?
Can we create a docker network over there? And how do we pass these properties inside the deployment yaml?

I have created a docker network named as "elk", and then passed it in the run arguments (as docker run --network=elk -h elasticsearch ....)
I am expecting to create this network in kubernetes cluster and then pass these properties to deployment yaml

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes does not have Docker's notion of separate per-application isolated networks.  You can't reproduce this Docker setup in Kubernetes and don't need to.  Also see [Services, Load Balancing, and Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/) in the Kubernetes documentation.

In Kubernetes you usually do not communicate directly with Pods (containers).  Instead, you also create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) matching each Deployment, and then [make calls to the Service name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and port.

If you're currently deploying containers with `docker run --net=...` then you can ignore that option when migrating to Kubernetes.  If you're using Compose, I'd suggest first trying to update the Compose setup to use only the Compose-provided `default` network, removing all of the `networks:` blocks.

For something like Elasticsearch, you probably want to run it in a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) which can also manage the per-replica storage.  This has specific requirements around corresponding Services, and it does provide a way to connect to a specific replica when you need to.  Relevantly to this question, if the StatefulSet is named `elasticsearch` then the Pods will be named `elasticsearch-0`, `elasticsearch-1`, and so on, and these names will also be visible as the **hostname**(8) inside the container, matching the `docker run -h` option.